# How to sign a string with x509 cert private key using RS256 Algorithm in c#?

Tags: c#

How to sign a string with x509 cert private key using RS256 Algorithm in c#?

I'm using the following code but it showing "Value was invalid." for the prKey1.SignData() method.

```
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();

            cert.Import(certFileServerPath, certPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            RSACryptoServiceProvider prKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
            RSACryptoServiceProvider prKey1 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            prKey1 .ImportParameters(prKey.ExportParameters(true));

            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputData);

            byte[] signature = prKey1.SignData(data, "SHA256withRSA");
            output = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
```

Hope to get some help on this.

Thank you

Comment: The 2nd parameter to `SignData` needs to be an instance of a hash algorithm, not the *name* of the algorithm. See the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.signdata

Comment: I updated the code to with the instance of hash algorithm but still the same error.var hashAlgName = new HashAlgorithmName("rsa-sha256");
 byte[] signature = prKey1.SignData(data, hashAlgName, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

Comment: What documentation did you refer to that indicates “rsa-sha256” is a supported hash algorithm name? I would suggest using `HashAlgorithmName.SHA256` instead.

Comment: Solved the issue with your suggestion. Thank you.